# django-admin: creating,saving and relating a m2m model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, manytomanyfield, m2m

I have two models:

```
class Production(models.Model):
    gallery = models.ManyToManyField(Gallery)

class Gallery(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
```

I have the m2m relationship in my productions admin, but I want that functionality that when I create a new Production, a default gallery is created and the relationship is registered between the two.

So far I can create the default gallery by overwriting the productions save:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    if not ( Gallery.objects.filter(name__exact="foo").exists() ):
        g = Gallery(name="foo")
        g.save()
        self.gallery.add(g)
```

This creates and saves the model instance (if it doesn't already exist), but I don't know how to register the relationship between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You register the relationship just as you have, by calling `add` on the `Production`.  The problem is that you're saving the `Gallery`, but not the `Production` whose `save` you've overridden.  You need to call `super(...).save(...)` at the end of your `save`:

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False):
    if not ( Gallery.objects.filter(name__exact="foo").exists() ):
        g = Gallery(name="foo")
        g.save()
        self.gallery.add(g)
    super(Production, self).save(force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
```

Furthermore, since you're dealing with two models here, you should use Django's signals for this, probably [post-save](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_save), which will also give you the `created` flag:

```
def create_default_gallery(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created and not Gallery.objects.filter(name__exact="foo").exists():
        g = Gallery(name="foo")
        g.save()
        instance.gallery.add(g)
models.signals.post_save.connect(create_default_gallery, sender=Production)
```

Though this still won't do what you say you want; if you really want to associate the default `Gallery` with every new `Production`, you'll want to do it even when you're not creating the default `Gallery`:

```
def create_default_gallery(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        g = Gallery.objects.get_or_create(name__exact="foo")
        g.save()
        instance.gallery.add(g)
models.signals.post_save.connect(create_default_gallery, sender=Production)
```

Comment: hey, thanks for that. Unfortunately I still have the same problem. I actually had the super(...).save(...) in the original I just forgot to include it in the original post. Even using the signals; it's creating the instance of the Gallery but not linking it to the production.

Comment: @pastylegs that's weird; can you manually add galleries to a production in the shell?